# example of a Schur-concave metric on density matrices

Tags: metrics, majorization

I am looking for an example of a metric/distance function $D(\rho,\sigma)$ which is Schur-concave apart from fidelity. In particular I am interested in the relation

$D(\rho, \sum_i p_i \sigma_i) \leq_{?} D(\rho, \sum_i q_i \sigma_i)$,

when $\vec{p}$ majorizes $\vec{q}$.

Comment: Do you mean if $\vec p$ majorizes $\vec q$, then you must have your inequality?

Comment: Yes. For a Schur-concave function.

Comment: Maybe I think there exists a counter-example that such $D$ does not exist? Suppose now we have $D\left( \rho ,\sigma _1 \right) < D\left( \rho ,\sigma _2 \right) $, then for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, we have $D\left[ \rho ,\left( 1-\epsilon \right) \sigma _1+\epsilon \sigma _2 \right] < D\left( \rho ,\sigma _2 \right) $. However, $\left( 1,0 \right) $ majorizes $\left( 1-\epsilon ,\epsilon \right) $.

Comment: Two things: 1. For the counter-example, we assume D is Schur-concave, and then further assume existence of the first inequality, right? But unless (1, 0) majorizes (0, 1) I'm not sure if the assumption itself is viable... 2. Square-root fidelity is an example of a Schur-concave function (since negative of fidelity is Schur-convex -- it's symmetric and jointly convex ).